# perform a function over a set of data and variables

Tags: python, function, dataset

I have a function which depends on 5 variables. I also have a set of data for those variables.

My question is how can I run the function for all the data? I would like to get a vector as a result.

```
def My_funct(a, b, c, d, e):
    #do something
```

my set of variables are:

```
a = [a1, a2, a3, a4....etc]
b = [b1, b2, b3, b4....etc]
c = [c1, c2, c3, c4....etc]
d = [d1, d2, d3, d4....etc]
e = [e1, e2, e3, e4....etc]
```

Any helpful will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you want to do. You can [map](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/map) a function through a collection if that's what you're asking.

Comment: You don't have a set of data. Sets and lists aren't the same thing, and five separate lists even less so. And I'm not sure what you mean by "vector"—sometimes people use that to mean a 1D numpy array, but that doesn't seem relevant here. If you don't know the terminology to explain what you want, that's fine, but then you need to demonstrate it better—show some sample input (actual input, not syntax errors), something you want to do, and what the output should look like.

Comment: I think you _may_ be looking for `for aa, bb, cc, dd, ee in zip(a, b, c, d, e):`, but that's really just a wild guess. Read about `zip` in the documentation to see if that sounds relevant.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient approach would be to use `numpy` arrays and to make sure your function is as vectorized as possible.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
b = np.array([5, 6, 7, 8])
c = np.array([9, 10, 11, 12])
d = np.array([13, 14, 15, 16])
e = np.array([17, 18, 19, 20])

def magic(a, b, c, d, e):
    return a + b + c + d + e

print(magic(a, b, c, d, e))
#  [45 50 55 60]
```

This can even be generalized for an arbitrary number of arrays:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
b = np.array([5, 6, 7, 8])
c = np.array([9, 10, 11, 12])
d = np.array([13, 14, 15, 16])
e = np.array([17, 18, 19, 20])

def magic(*arrays):
    return sum(arrays)

print(magic(a, b, c, d, e))
#  [45 50 55 60]

print(magic(a, b))
# [ 6  8 10 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a lambda function over each line of the matrix (which contains all the data).

```
#df = matrix with data
result = df.apply(lambda x: my_funct(x['a'], x['b'], x['c'], x['d'], x['e']), axis=1)
```

Hope this might be useful.